# Prove that if $LCM(a,b) = GCF(a,b)^2$, then $b = a^2$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

How to prove that if $LCM(a,b) = GCF(a,b)^2$, then $b = a^2$ ?

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539205/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the conclusion isn't exactly true. It should be $b=a^2$ OR $a=b^2$, by symmetry.

Anyway, it's false: take $a=12$, $b=18$. Then $\gcd(a,b)=6$, $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=36$, yet $b\ne a^2$.

The assertion would be true if  $\gcd(a,b)$ were a prime power.

Comment: To explain how to construct counterexamples, let $(a)_p$ be the highest power of $p$ dividing $a$, e.g., $(12)_2$=4.  Then the conditions imply for every prime $p$ that either $(a)_p=(b)_p^2$ or $(b)_p=(a)_p^2$.  If $(a)_p=(b)_p^2$ for every $p$, then $a=b^2$.  However, if we have some $p$'s with one equality and other $p$'s with the other, we will get counterexamples.  In this case, we have $(12)_2=4=(18)_2^2$, and $(18)_3=9=(12)_3^2$.  So the conditions imply something is going on, but we can wind up with a mismatch.