# Suppose a, b are integers and LCM(a, b) = GCD(a, b)^2. What can be said about the prime decompositions of a and b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

Unsure how to approach the problem besides using the fact that the LCM(a,b) * GCD(a,b) = a*b. I see the implication that the GCD(a,b)^3 = a * b. Perhaps it means a and b are different powers of the same prime decomposition?

Say a = 3 and b = 3^2: then gcd(a,b) = 3 -> gcd(a,b)^3 = 3^3 = 27 and a*b = 3 * 3^2 = 3^3

Then gcd(a,b)^3 = a*b since 3^3 = 3^3

I understand this implication but having trouble applying it generally to the prime decompositions of a and b.

Can it be said that the prime decomposition of b equals the prime decomposition of a^2 assuming b > a?

Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps some example will help. Take $a=18, b=12$. Also, can you conclude that $a$ and $b$ have the same prime factors up to multiplicity (i.e. the *set* of primes dividing $a$ is the same as the set of primes dividing $b$)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime factors of $x$ and $y$ in prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539205/prime-factors-of-x-and-y-in-prime-number) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D(a%2Cb)%3D%5Cgcd(a%2Cb)%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%20decomposition&p=1).

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\gcd(a,b)^2$. Now, let $p$ be any prime number, and let $n,m\ge 0$ be non-negative integers, such that $p^n$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $a$ and $p^m$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $b$.

Now, the largest power of $p$ which divides $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is $p^{\max(n,m)}$. Can you see why?

The largest power of $p$ which divides $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)^2$ is $p^{2\cdot\min(n,m)}$. Can you see why?

Now, because prime factorizations are unique, it follows from $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\gcd(a,b)^2$ that $\max(n,m)=2\min(n,m)$. In other words, if we look at $n$ and $m$, one of the two is twice the other one.

---

So we have found a necessary condition on the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$. It is also sufficient, but I leave this as a challenge to you.

---

We are now also in a position to generate a lot of examples. Pick a random prime, say $7$. Pick a pair of integers where one is twice the other, say $2$ and $4$. Raise your prime to these powers. We find $7^2=49$ and $7^4 = 2401$.

Repeat this process as often as you like. Let's take $2$ as our next prime, and $5$ and $10$ as our exponents. We find $2^5=32$ and $2^{10}=1024$.

Let's  take $19$ as our next prime, with exponents $1$ and $2$. We find $19^1=19$ and $19^2=361$.

Okay, now we have a few pairs of prime powers. From each pair, pick one. Say we pick $49$, $1024$ and $19$. Multiply them together to get $a$. We find $a=49\cdot 1024\cdot 19 = 953344$. Now take the *other* prime power of each pair, so $2401$, $32$ and $361$, and multiply those together to get $b$. So $b=2401\cdot 32\cdot 361=27736352$.

Finally, let's test. We find
$$\operatorname{lcm}(953344,27736352)=887563264=29792^2 = \gcd(953344,27736352)^2,$$
like we wanted!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the reminder. My enthusiasm got the better of me